# wxPython and CEF Python 3

Tags: python, wxpython, chromium-embedded, cefpython

Looking at the example file in CEF Python 3 on Windows.

When running the Python example scripts, it opens a debug window in the Windows command prompt.

I want to know how not to show this?

Just to state the obvious:

**DEBUG = True -- Does not make a difference, it just stops the debugging inside that window but the window still shows.**

This is the example.py file:

```
# CEF Python 3 example application.

# Checking whether python architecture and version are valid, otherwise an obfuscated
# error will be thrown when trying to load cefpython.pyd with a message "DLL load failed".
import platform
if platform.architecture()[0] != "32bit":
    raise Exception("Architecture not supported: %s" % platform.architecture()[0])

import os, sys
libcef_dll = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)),
        'libcef.dll')
if os.path.exists(libcef_dll):
    # Import the local module.
    if 0x02070000 <= sys.hexversion < 0x03000000:
        import cefpython_py27 as cefpython
    elif 0x03000000 <= sys.hexversion < 0x04000000:
        import cefpython_py32 as cefpython
    else:
        raise Exception("Unsupported python version: %s" % sys.version)
else:
    # Import the package.
    from cefpython3 import cefpython

import cefwindow
import win32con
import win32gui
import time

DEBUG = True

def GetApplicationPath(file=None):
    import re, os
    # If file is None return current directory without trailing slash.
    if file is None:
        file = ""
    # Only when relative path.
    if not file.startswith("/") and not file.startswith("\\") and (
            not re.search(r"^[\w-]+:", file)):
        if hasattr(sys, "frozen"):
            path = os.path.dirname(sys.executable)
        elif "__file__" in globals():
            path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
        else:
            path = os.getcwd()
        path = path + os.sep + file
        path = re.sub(r"[/\\]+", re.escape(os.sep), path)
        path = re.sub(r"[/\\]+$", "", path)
        return path
    return str(file)

def ExceptHook(excType, excValue, traceObject):
    import traceback, os, time, codecs
    # This hook does the following: in case of exception write it to
    # the "error.log" file, display it to the console, shutdown CEF
    # and exit application immediately by ignoring "finally" (_exit()).
    errorMsg = "\n".join(traceback.format_exception(excType, excValue,
            traceObject))
    errorFile = GetApplicationPath("error.log")
    try:
        appEncoding = cefpython.g_applicationSettings["string_encoding"]
    except:
        appEncoding = "utf-8"
    if type(errorMsg) == bytes:
        errorMsg = errorMsg.decode(encoding=appEncoding, errors="replace")
    try:
        with codecs.open(errorFile, mode="a", encoding=appEncoding) as fp:
            fp.write("\n[%s] %s\n" % (
                    time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"), errorMsg))
    except:
        print("cefpython: WARNING: failed writing to error file: %s" % (
                errorFile))
    # Convert error message to ascii before printing, otherwise
    # you may get error like this:
    # | UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters
    errorMsg = errorMsg.encode("ascii", errors="replace")
    errorMsg = errorMsg.decode("ascii", errors="replace")
    print("\n"+errorMsg+"\n")
    cefpython.QuitMessageLoop()
    cefpython.Shutdown()
    os._exit(1)

def InitDebugging():
    # Whether to print & log debug messages
    if DEBUG:
        cefpython.g_debug = True
        cefpython.g_debugFile = GetApplicationPath("debug.log")
        cefwindow.g_debug = True

def CefAdvanced():
    sys.excepthook = ExceptHook
    InitDebugging()

    appSettings = dict()
    appSettings["log_file"] = GetApplicationPath("debug.log")
    appSettings["log_severity"] = cefpython.LOGSEVERITY_INFO
    appSettings["release_dcheck_enabled"] = True # Enable only when debugging
    appSettings["browser_subprocess_path"] = "%s/%s" % (
            cefpython.GetModuleDirectory(), "subprocess")
    cefpython.Initialize(appSettings)

    wndproc = {
        win32con.WM_CLOSE: CloseWindow,
        win32con.WM_DESTROY: QuitApplication,
        win32con.WM_SIZE: cefpython.WindowUtils.OnSize,
        win32con.WM_SETFOCUS: cefpython.WindowUtils.OnSetFocus,
        win32con.WM_ERASEBKGND: cefpython.WindowUtils.OnEraseBackground
    }

    browserSettings = dict()
    browserSettings["universal_access_from_file_urls_allowed"] = True
    browserSettings["file_access_from_file_urls_allowed"] = True

    windowHandle = cefwindow.CreateWindow(title="CEF Python 3 example", 
            className="cefpython3_example", width=800, height=600, 
            icon="icon.ico", windowProc=wndproc)
    windowInfo = cefpython.WindowInfo()
    windowInfo.SetAsChild(windowHandle)
    browser = cefpython.CreateBrowserSync(windowInfo, browserSettings,
            navigateUrl=GetApplicationPath("example.html"))
    cefpython.MessageLoop()
    cefpython.Shutdown()

def CloseWindow(windowHandle, message, wparam, lparam):
    browser = cefpython.GetBrowserByWindowHandle(windowHandle)
    browser.CloseBrowser()
    return win32gui.DefWindowProc(windowHandle, message, wparam, lparam)

def QuitApplication(windowHandle, message, wparam, lparam):
    win32gui.PostQuitMessage(0)
    return 0

if __name__ == "__main__":
    CefAdvanced()
```

Answer (score 1):

I got it right, but it was actually the way in which I used py2exe.

In the setup.py file I had to change:

```
setup(
    console=['wxwindow.py']
    ,data_files = get_data_files()
    ,options={"py2exe":{"dll_excludes":dll_excludes, 'optimize': 2}}
    ,zipfile = "shared.lib"
)

setup(
    window=['wxwindow.py']
    ,data_files = get_data_files()
    ,options={"py2exe":{"dll_excludes":dll_excludes, 'optimize': 2}}
    ,zipfile = "shared.lib"
)
```

SO:

```
window=['wxwindow.py']
```

Comment: For me, I had to make it window*s* (note: plural)